# How to Slide or Move this Set of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of **seven** div's with the following properties:

```
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
```

I have a wrapper div containing these seven blocks with **only enough room to fit four** and change.

The overflow is hidden.

How can I make this function so that when you clicked and dragged horizontally, or swiped with your finger on mobile, the entire row of div blocks would slide to show the previously hidden ones?

Please refer to [this jsFiddle for the example](http://jsfiddle.net/2pRBg/).

We can use css or jQuery here.

*Bonus, show fractions of otherwise entirely hidden div's at the edges of the container.

Comment: I am willing to try anything, but I honestly don't know where to begin.

Comment: I think it would have to be some sort of jQuery method for the divs to be moveable inside the wrapper container.

Comment: Try jQuery.kinetic for this http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/2pRBg/6/

Comment: @louisbros, that is exactly what I was looking for. Please post an answer so other users may learn this also!

Comment: I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has mentioned [jQuery.Kinetic](https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic) I'll add this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="first">First</div>
        <div class="second">Second</div>
        <div class="third">Third</div>
        <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
        <div class="fifth">Fifth</div>
        <div class="sixth">Sixth</div>
        <div class="seventh">Seventh</div>
    </div>
</div>


$('.carousel').kinetic();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/2pRBg/6/

Comment: The best and most simplistic solution. I like how once the divs have reached the end of the container, they stop. Brilliant! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's hard to see in the demo but you can also 'throw' the div so it keeps moving after mouseup

Answer (score 2):

Based on jfriend00's answer I modified this so it will work on touch/click and move with the mouse.

```
var last_x = null;
var holding = false;
//Mark the wrapper as clicked/touched
$('.wrapper').mousedown(function(){
    holding=true;
});
//We do this on document so that even if movement goes outside of the container the event will fire
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    holding=false;
});

$('.wrapper').mousemove(function(e){
    if(last_x === null || !holding) //If this is the first movement
    {
        last_x = e.pageX;
        return;
    }
    var ammount = e.pageX - last_x;
    $('.slider',this).css('margin-left', '+=' + ammount);
    last_x = e.pageX;
});
```

The gist of how this works is that when the mousedown event is detected on the container the script starts tracking all mouse movement and moves the content with the mouse. When the mouse is released it stop tracking movement.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NvJam/2/

Answer (score 1):

[`see here`](http://jsfiddle.net/2pRBg/1/)

```
 .wrapper {
        width: 900px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, that solves the bonus problem. Any idea how I could move these divs left and right to the edge of the container?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an additional container div and use absolute positioning on that div to move the items left/right.  Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7edc9/

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="first">First</div>
        <div class="second">Second</div>
        <div class="third">Third</div>
        <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
        <div class="fifth">Fifth</div>
        <div class="sixth">Sixth</div>
        <div class="seventh">Seventh</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You weren't entirely clear how you wanted to move them on non-touch screens, but here's some event handlers that work on buttons:

```
$("#left").click(function() {
    $(".slider").stop(true, true).animate({left: "-=125px"}, 500);
});
$("#right").click(function() {
    $(".slider").stop(true, true).animate({left: "+=125px"}, 500);
});
```

Something similar could be hooked up for touch events.

Comment: i think the OP is trying to amend a drag concept over those divs.

Comment: Yes I am, but this is a perfect starting point for me to learn hence the +1. Any idea how to make this dragable with the mouse in addition to buttons? I imagine some sort of plugin would take care of that or is it some simple jQuery? And, what about restricting movement once the edge of the container is reached? But, I think I know where to start looking for those answers. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Even better solution: use the JQuery UI draggable:

```
$('.slider').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DCuGV/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I think the perfect answer is louisbros, however, look at the comments under the question!

Comment: That looks like the one! I figured a plugin to do this must exist, as it is such a common need, but I was unaware of what it may be. Good find louisbros.